# ssh-keygen -y error: load failed

Tags: ssh-keygen

I want to check correctness of a pair of `RSA` key. As far as I know, I can crate a public key from a private key by using the below command, and then compare two public key if are equal or not:

`ssh-keygen -y -f <PRIVATE-KEY>`

The question is that, why when I use the above command, It can't load the key?

[image]

Is there any other way to check correctness of a pair of RSA keys?

---

FYI :

```
root@bt:~# ssh-keygen -y -v -f /root/Desktop/PROIVA 
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase: 
debug1: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
load failed
root@bt:~# file /root/Desktop/PROIVA 
/root/Desktop/PROIVA: data
root@bt:~#
```

---

```
root@bt:~# openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform der -noout -text
unable to load Private Key
1819:error:0D094065:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad class:a_set.c:190:
1819:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
1819:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=RSA
1819:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:d2i_pr.c:99:
root@bt:~# 
root@bt:~# 
root@bt:~# openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform DER -out /root/Desktop/PROIVA.pem -outform PEM
unable to load Private Key
1820:error:0D094065:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad class:a_set.c:190:
1820:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
1820:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=RSA
1820:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:d2i_pr.c:99:
root@bt:~# 
root@bt:~#
```

But the below command creates `Proiva.der` on the desktop:

```
root@bt:~# openssl base64 -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -out /root/Desktop/Proiva.der
root@bt:~#
```

---

```
root@bt:~# openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/Proiva.der -inform der -noout -text
unable to load Private Key
1826:error:0D094065:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad class:a_set.c:190:
1826:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
1826:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=RSA
1826:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:d2i_pr.c:99:
root@bt:~#
```

---

This is a base64 view of my public/private files :

**Private :**

```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```

**Public :**

```
m37jkNportKxhOtP84bKXPY5JR16dzt2ZgdnGNrx7Q9u31jkn2lUPxDwdjlTzU8sIWUxHP4inC56
sxlbv9oeQQxhzF0CxclBuiR1kkfzRVMoEiXmacbozqM4+oh/+Bd1+jok25BQPnXkOq5tu/SIclkv
9zL20p+YsqL0esPUJvcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAQ==
```

Note that I generate the above base64 view of my files, via [this](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) online tool.

Comment: Can you add a `-v` to ssh-keygen command? And what does `file /root/Desktop/PROIVA` return?  Ad some more debugging info. No need for Images though

Comment: @val0x00ff Please take a look at **Update** section.Thanks

Comment: Can you do an `id` as root and make sure your `uid` is 0?

Comment: @MaxMackie Yes, `root@bt:~# id`, And answer :
`uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

Comment: What is the output of `head -n1 /root/Desktop/PROIVA`?

Comment: @TimothyMartin : It is some unreadable text : `root@bt:~# head -n1 /root/Desktop/PROIVA`
And out out is : 
`�~���h�ұ��O���\�9%zw;vfg��n�X��iT?�v9S�O,!e1�"�.z�[��A
                                                            a�]��A�$u�G�ES(%�i��Σ8���u�:$ېP>u�:�m���rY/�2�ҟ����z��&�`

Comment: It appears there is something not right with your private key.  Ideally, the file type would be ascii text and the output of the `head` command would be `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` or something similar.  How did you generate the private key?

Comment: @TimothyMartin I created the keys by a SDK for my `senselock EL EliteVI v2.x` doungle! You can find it here : http://www.senselock.com/en/productinfor.php?nid=181&id=142&pid=

Comment: @TheGoodUser  It seems your key is converted into `DER` format.  `openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform DER -out /root/Desktop/PROIVA -outform PEM`  Then try to `ssh-keygen` command again.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your file is in `DER` binary format. You first need to convert the file into e.g `PEM` format.

To verify the file is in `DER` binary format run:

```
openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform der -noout -text
```

If it returns something like the following, then it is indeed in `DER` format.

```
Private-Key: (1024 bit)
modulus:
    00:a9:07:0c:59:20:6f:48:c0:34:59:c1:10:17:f5:
................................
..............................
```

Run the following:

```
 openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform DER -out /root/Desktop/PROIVA.pem -outform PEM
```

Now your `PROVIA` file is converted into `PEM` format.

Finally run.

```
ssh-keygen -y -v -f /root/Desktop/PROIVA.pem
```

Comment: `root@bt:~# openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform DER -out /root/Desktop/PROIVA.pem -outform PEM
unable to load Private Key
1767:error:0D094065:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad class:a_set.c:190:
1767:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
1767:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=RSA
1767:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:d2i_pr.c:99:
root@bt:~#`

Unforunately not work!

Comment: And for the first command :

`root@bt:~# openssl rsa -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -inform der -noout -text
unable to load Private Key
1768:error:0D094065:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad class:a_set.c:190:
1768:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1316:
1768:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:380:Type=RSA
1768:error:0D09A00D:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_PrivateKey:ASN1 lib:d2i_pr.c:99:
root@bt:~#`

Comment: Can you run: `openssl base64 -in /root/Desktop/PROIVA -out /root/Desktop/Proiva.der`  and update your question with the info.

Comment: Yes! I could! the Proiva.der created on the /root/Desktop. What now? :)

Comment: Now read the answer above. and see if you get similar results

Comment: Results added in **Update 3** section :(

Comment: @TheGoodUser you really need to provide more information about the PROIVA file. How did you generate it?.

Comment: If you want, I can send the file to you. I generate that file with **Elite EL SDK Basic v 3.3.2** in this page : http://www.senselock.com/en/productinfor.php?nid=181&id=142&pid=    (under resources tab)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16627/discussion-between-val0x00ff-and-thegooduser).